# Extjs Alerts not Centering in Modern

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6-modern

I have an issue with Extjs Alerts in modern toolkit. I need to display an alert but sometimes it renders perfectly and sometimes it overlaps the screen just like in the image above,

Below is my

```
 Ext.Msg.alert("Title", 'Message');
```

[image: Alert not Centering Snapshot]

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Issac: reproduce your issue in sencha fiddle for required sencha version you are using .

Comment: Ext.Msg.alert("Title", 'Message'); there is no error here i think problem is somewhere else

Comment: @Tejas1991 Reproducing this issue is quite tricky as this only happens when I generate and Android App or an iOS app as in the picture, But in the browser it works okay. If you run it in android, It overlaps the screen.

Comment: @HarshitShah I am using 6.2

Comment: @SalmanhassanOkZ, I think so to so I am trying to recreate the issue, which may be hard cos this happens on only an emulator for both iOS and Android

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late of a response but I had the same issue. Need to check the transform for the message window.

```
var alertMsg = Ext.Msg.alert("Title", 'Message')
alertMsg.setStyle('transform:translate3d(65px, 218px, 0px);');
```